# PHP: Checking which boxes are marked in a form and then storing those values in a database

Tags: php, checkbox

So the html code displays a form with checkboxes.

The php code is the part I'm having trouble with.

I don't understand why if `( isset( $_POST["Submit"] ) )` isn't evaluating to true and thus printing "Yes, mail is set".

That's the first and most simplest problem I'm dealing with.

After I find out how to check which boxes are being checked, how do I then store those values as a column on a table of my database on bluehost?

Thank you.

**HTML:**

```
<html>
<form method="POST"> 
<table style="width:300px">

<tr>

  <td>  <font color="#bf2624">
  Protein 1 <input type="checkbox" name="nutrient[Protein 1]" value="protein 1" /><br/> </td>

  <td> <font color="#c67622">
  Carbohydrate 1 <input type="checkbox" name="nutrient[]" value="carbohydrate 1"/><br/></td> 

  <td>  <font color ="#0d3aa3">
  Fat 1 <input type="checkbox" name="nutrient[]" value="fat 1" /><br/></td>

</tr>

<tr>
  <td>  <font color="#bf2624">
  Protein 2 <input type="checkbox" name="nutrient[]" value="protein 2" /><br/></td>

  <td><font color="#c67622">
  Carbohydrate 2 <input type="checkbox" name="nutrient[]" value="carbohydrate 2"   /><br/></td> 

  <td>   <font color ="#0d3aa3">
  Fat 2 <input type="checkbox" name="nutrient[]" value="fat 2" /><br/><br/></td>

</tr>

<tr>
  <td>  <font color="#bf2624">
  Protein 3 <input type="checkbox" name="nutrient[]" value="protein 3" /><br/></td>

  <td><font color="#c67622">
  Carbohydrate 3 <input type="checkbox" name="nutrient[]" value="carbohydrate 3" /><br/><br/>                         

</td> 

</tr>

<tr>
  <td>  <font color="#bf2624">
  Protein 4 <input type="checkbox" name="nutrient[]" value="protein 4" /><br/></td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td>  <font color="#bf2624">
  Protein 5 <input type="checkbox" name="nutrient[]" value="protein 5" /><br/></td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td>  <font color="#bf2624">
  Protein 6 <input type="checkbox" name="nutrient[]" value="protein 6" /><br/><br/></td>
</tr>


</table>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
<input type='reset' value='Reset'>



<?php  
if ( isset( $_POST["Submit"] ) ) { 
    //if (isset($_POST["Protein 1"]) && !empty($_POST["Protein 1"])) {
        echo "Yes, mail is set";    
    //}else{  
        //echo "No, mail is not set";
    //}
}
?>

</form>
```

Comment: The value inside `$_POST` refers to the `name` of your input element. As I see, you haven't set the `name` for your submit button.

Comment: +1 to @ICanHasKittenz - that will solve your first problem. As for your second problem - waaay too broad. Google around for a tutorial on basic php/mysql operations.

Comment: if(isset($_POST['nutrient'])) {

}

Comment: Do you mean just changing the submit button code to: <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" /> because that doesn't seem to work?

Comment: Yes, that's the right idea. To troubleshoot, start small - get rid of your other inputs and just see if you can get the submit button to work by itself. Expand from there.